# Proxy Authentication and node request

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit, node-request, proxy-authentication

I am trying to send a get request to a site over https using request. I am however, behind a proxy, which requires authentication to use. When i try to add the authentication however it fails to connect to the site.

I have tried adding the authentication in the proxy url like:

```
var proxyUrl = "http://" + 'user' + ":" + 'password' + "@" + 'url:8080';
var request = require('request').defaults({proxy: proxyUrl});
```

I also tried to add the authorization to the header however this had also the same problem

```
headers: {
            'Proxy-Authorization': new Buffer('user:password').toString('base64')
}
```

---

It seems the proxy is coming back with the auth response however request dosent seem to send anything after that so it does not actually login. Is there some more config i need to add?

Comment: Or try [`request-ntlm`](https://github.com/FrankyBoy/request-ntlm) or [`request-simple-ntlm`](https://github.com/msathis/request-simple-ntlm).

Comment: Yes just looking at [proxying-agent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxying-agent) which seems to support NTLM proxies. Seems a bit of disparity between what its readme says and whats in the source though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the Proxy we are using is using NTLM authentication. So in order to authenticate I must use the NTLM protocol instead of Basic. I will look into using [Proxing-agent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxying-agent) to do this authentication. Or as mentioned by [robertklep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893780/robertklep) there are some options for directly authenticating with the server using NTLM.

Managed to implement this using [NTLM.js](https://github.com/capriza/node-proxying-agent/blob/master/lib/ntlm.js) from the node-proxying-agent and [request](https://github.com/request/request) using the following description of the [protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd925287(v=office.12).aspx).

Comment: Any success doing this?

Comment: I have managed to build the messages to send however the server is still coming back with auth fail so some work yet to be done. Its not the highest priority for me at the moment however i will update this when i have it complete.